# how python import packages with multiple copies

Tags: python, import, path

I was believing that when importing a package, it would search from `sys.path` and use the first hit for import. However, it seems not true:

```
import mpl_toolkits
print(mpl_toolkits.__path__)
```

And it outputs:

```
['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/mpl_toolkits', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits']
```

Can someone please explain to me how exactly python looks for packages if it is installed multiple times in the machine (in different location searchable by `sys.path`)? Or a pointer to relevant reference would be good.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I think you are right this is because of python's feature of "Namespace Packages" and the packages takes the two locations for storage.

Answer (score 0):

when you import a module, python  uses PYTHON PATH (system variable that contains a list of folders) and loops to search for importable module.
Python will test if it is a package (folder containing **init**.py) or a module (*.py). it will stop on first module found if no module is found python raises an `import error`